# Which method I should track to know a new request comes into .net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, coreclr, clr-profiling-api

I'm implementing profiler to track http requests coming to .net core applications hosted in IIS. I'm using coreclr profiling api to hook method enter/exit.

Which method I should track to know a new http request coming into my application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a middle ware and configure ASP.NET Core to use it. It should receive requests, process it, then pass it along with the pipeline.

For more information see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks. To configure middleware I need to add it in startup.cs , right? But I don't want to touch my .net core application code. Is there any default middleware available in .net core applications which will be always executed. So that I can track it?

Comment: Do you mean an already available middle ware which monitor requests and is extensible too? I do not know a case by the moment, but I am pretty sure that there a bunch of them available on the nugget.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not clear.
Do dotnet applications run any middleware by default. So that we no need to configure it manually in statup. I can see usemvc middleware in .net core web application. Is this usemvc middleware mandatory to run .net core web applications. If no, Is there any middleware which must be always used in .net core web application?

Comment: I am not sure about the answer, sorry.